# Why does FirstOrDefault and ToList return different results in certain cases?

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity model that references itself like:

```
public class User
{       

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(150)]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? CreatedByUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedByUserId")]
    public ICollection<User> CreatedUsers { get; set; }    

    [ForeignKey("CreatedByUserId")]
    public User CreatedByUser { get; set; }
}
```

And everything is working fine until I try to `include` the `CreatedByUser` property along with `Take` method. Consider following examples:

```
 // say that user 'Rita' was created by 'Tom'    
 var result1 = await Dependencies.AppDbContext.Users.Where(m => m.FirstName == "Rita").Take(1).Include(m => m.CreatedByUser).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
 // result1 = 'Tom', but I would expect it to be 'Rita';

 var result2 = await Dependencies.AppDbContext.Users.Where(m => m.FirstName == "Rita").Include(m => m.CreatedByUser).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
// result2 = 'Rita' which is what I expect
```

Strange thing is that when I call `ToList()` on query from result1, it returns **correct result**. Same thing when I view results in Visual studio debug.

Can someone explain what is going on? I guess it doesn't matter much since calling `FirstOrDefault` sets the `Top` parameter of the underlying SQL query, but still.. This gave me quite a headache debugging.

Comment: Read up on Deferred Execution: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/

Comment: Hey, just tried that and it yields the same results. I really don't get why is this happening. Almost seems like a bug to me.

Comment: Are you sure that both Tom and Rita has value on their `CreatedByUser` fields? Because CreatedByUserId is nullable, and if the value is null, then .Include won't show the entries that has null value.

Comment: Try inserting the `.Include(m => m.CreatedByUser)` before your `.Where()` statement, and check if there are any differences.

Comment: Deleted my own comment bc i tried it myself. No this is not a bug, i think it is because you are saying Users.Where().Take(1) -> now nothing happens till this point because you arent telling what you want. like you said adding ToList() resolves the query and then you can call for other includes. Have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: BTW your second query should work that way too: var result2 = await Dependencies.AppDbContext.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FirstName == "Rita").Include(m => m.CreatedByUser);

Comment: I've tried using the include before the 'where', but the result is again the same. To Burak: I'm pretty sure the data is correct because the query results correctly with ToList() or without the Take parameter.
I was about to try the 'FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.FirstName == "Rita").Include(m => m.CreatedByUser);' but this doesn't seem to be the correct syntax as Include is not available at this point. Thank you all for all the hints so far :-)